# How to display Shipping Charge in Header Mini Cart in Magento 1.9.X?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I want to display Shipping Charge in Header Mini Cart same as cart page.
There is only display Grand Total.

Please suggest me how to get shipping charge in header mini cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this code in your app/design/frontend/package_name/Theme_name/template/checkout/cart/minicart.phtml

```
<?php if(!$_cartQty)
     $_cartQty = 0;
     $_shipping = $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice
     (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount());
?>
```

and print this price as

```
 <?php echo $_shipping ?>
```

where ever you want to get price.